# JSForce connection with connected app returns undefined

Tags: javascript, connected-apps, jsforce

I am using the below code to establish a connection with Salesforce connected app -

```
const express = require('express'); //Adding Express
const http = require('http'); //Adding http
const jsforce = require('jsforce'); //Adding JsForce

const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
let accessToken;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        // you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
        oauth2: {
            loginUrl: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
            clientId: 'clientId',
            clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
            redirectUri: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth/success'
        }

    });
    var username = 'username';
    var password = 'password+security token';
    conn.login(username, password, function (err, userInfo) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }
        console.log(conn.accessToken);
        console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
        console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
        console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
        res.send('heySalesforce : JSForce Connect Succeeded!');
    });
});
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Here is the snip of the connected app in Salesforce -
[image]
I dont get anything printed out of the app.get function to the console. Could someone point what careless mistake I am causing here.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. What you have is one side of the story - the client side - thus making your example incomplete and not reproducible.

Comment: The other side is a connected app in Salesforce. I have added the snip to the post.

Comment: JSforce doc (at least the first code sample on https://jsforce.github.io/document/#connection) is wrong with respect to Resource Owner Password Credentials flow. Not only the doc is wrong, the flow has been [outlawed by the industry](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-24.html#name-resource-owner-password-cre) due to (severe) security issues and SF defaults turn off this flow for newer orgs.  Reimplement the connection based on Authorization Code (aka `jsforce.OAuth2`) flow.

Comment: @identigral Yes, I saw that and was able to fix it.